# Django get_FOO_display for custom form not working

Tags: django, django-forms

So this is my form:

```
class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    answer = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, widget=forms.RadioSelect())

    def __init__(self, question=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QuestionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['answer'].choices = [(a.answer, a.answer) for a in Answer.objects.filter(question=question)]

    class Meta:
        model = Questions
        fields = ('answer', 'importance' )
```

When a user selects an `answer` it shows all `Answer` objects. Here are my views:

```
def questions(request):
    new_forms = []
    q = Questions.objects.all()[0]
    if request.method =='POST':
        #form = QuestionForm(request.POST or None)
        for forms in new_forms:
            if forms.is_valid():
                new = forms.save(commit=False)
                #get the user's inputs to the QuestionForm and save them
                UserAnswer(user=request.user, answer=new.cleaned_data['answer'], question=new.question)
                UserAnswer.save()

    else:
        instance=Questions.objects.all().filter(owner=request.user)[0]
        #form = QuestionForm(question=q, instance=q)

    for a in Questions.objects.all():
        new_forms.append(QuestionForm(question=a, instance=a))
    return render_to_response("questions/base.html", locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm very confused by what you are doing.

```
            print new.fields['id_answer_2'].value
            print get_id_answer_2_display()
```

You `save(commit=False)` a ModelForm which returns a model *instance*. It should not even have a fields attribute (you would be getting an AttributeError here).

2: you next call `get_id_answer_2_display()` which doesn't appear to even be the right field (never mind that you call it as a standalone function).

Your ModelForm suggests you have an `answer` field, thus to use `get_FOO_display`, you'd need to call `new.get_answer_display()`

Comment: let me clarify what I'm doing. I have a `Question` model and it has associated `Answer`s. Users should be able to select their answer to each question. Those answers will be saved to `UserAnswers` like `UserAnswer(user=request.user,question=question, answer=answer)`. I can get the form to display properly with what I did above (I couldn't figure out how to do this with Formsets) but I cannot save UserAnswer correctly. I've updated my answer to match what I'm trying to do better.

Comment: What is the problem? If there are errors, you must post them. Based on what I'm seeing, your current code should throw errors. new.cleaned_data should NOT work / exist. Saving a ModelForm returns instances, not forms.